# Calling an IBM Watson API via HTTP from an application written in C/C++ and running locally?

Tags: http, ibm-watson

We are a Watson Build 2018 Phase 2 contestant.  To create my prototype, I am integrating Watson capabilities into the [rules language](http://WWW.XTRAN-LLC.com/xtran.html#rules-lang) of [XTRAN](http://WWW.XTRAN-LLC.com), our expert system that automates the analysis, transformation, and translation of computer languages, as well as data and text.  To be accepted, my prototype must use at least one Watson API and "must be developed on IBM Cloud".  Am I correct in thinking that I must install an HTTP client capability into my application and use that to call the Watson API?  If my application runs locally and uses HTTP to call a Watson API in the cloud, does that satisfy the requirement that my prototype be "developed on IBM Cloud"?  Where can I find examples of doing this, assuming that I am able to create and execute HTTP requests such as POST and GET using an HTTP client linked into my system?